# How a commandline become String[] args?

Tags: java

As we all know, in java main class have a static main function which args is String[] args
`public static void main(String[] args)`.
My question is how commandline arg1 arg2 arg3 in  `java Main arg1 arg2 arg3` become String[] args? Or where is code for parse 'arg1 arg2 arg3' to String[] args?
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: decompile the compiler and read the code

Comment: @Stultuske Wrong advice. A) it is not the compiler, but the JVM. B) I am sure that no decompilation is necessary. This is for sure _somewhere_ freely available in the open jdk sources. How long it would take to find it ... different story ;-)

Comment: @cxco have updated my answer please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

`public static void main(String[] args)` method is out of the box recognized by the JRE as the entry point method. And it's argument are recognized as commandline args (space separated).

**Edit** I have managed to find source code for this [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/bin/java.c). Hope you are able to understand it. Look at line no. 349 to quick start.

Comment: That might or might not be what the OP is asking about.

Comment: I think the OP is wondering what code is responsible for parsing the command line into a `String[]`.

Comment: well OP says how not what code is doing it. Answer to how is - jvm recognise this method signature. How it's code can be seen in jvm implementation

Comment: I also want to know  what code is doing this。If you know this ，please tell me where is the code @VinayPrajapati

Comment: looking up for same. but i don't know if you would be able to understand that code or not.

Comment: Have updated my answer. please have a look.